# New object with HQL

Tags: hibernate, object, hql, playframework

Trying to create an object from an HQL query, but just can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Query:

```
String query = "SELECT product.code, SUM(product.price), COUNT(product.code)
from Product AS product
GROUP BY product.code"
```

(or should I use new MyCustomList(product.code, SUM(... , even though it's not mapped?)
Now I want to cast this returned list into a similar object:

```
class MyCustomList{
  public String code;
  public BigDecimal price;
  public int total;

  // Constructor
  public MyCustomList(String code, String price, int total){ //...
```

Retrieving the data:

```
// This throws ClassCastException    
List<MyCustomList> list = MyClass.find(query).fetch();
```

Using Play framework

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I think that the section [15.6. The select clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select) covers what you're trying to achieve:

> #### [15.6. The select clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select)
>
> ...
>
> Queries can return multiple objects
>   and/or properties as an array of type
>   `Object[]`:
>
> ```
> select mother, offspr, mate.name
> from DomesticCat as mother
>     inner join mother.mate as mate
>     left outer join mother.kittens as offspr
> ```
>
> Or as a `List`:
>
> ```
> select new list(mother, offspr, mate.name)
> from DomesticCat as mother
>     inner join mother.mate as mate
>     left outer join mother.kittens as offspr
> ```
>
> Or - assuming that the class `Family`
>   has an appropriate constructor - as an
>   actual typesafe Java object:
>
> ```
> select new Family(mother, mate, offspr)
> from DomesticCat as mother
>     join mother.mate as mate
>     left join mother.kittens as offspr
> ```

In your case, you probably want:

```
SELECT new MyCustomList(product.code, SUM(product.price), COUNT(product.code))
from Product AS product
GROUP BY product.code
```

Where `MyCustomList` is not necessarily a mapped entity.

Comment: I tried the new MyCustomList quite a few times, but if I remember correctly (not at that machine atm) it gave me the ClassNotFound excepton, though the classes are in the same package under Play! models.

Comment: @Indrek: Use the fully qualified name: `select new com.acme.MyCustomList(...) from ...`

Comment: @PascalThivent could you please look at my problem [How to write HQL JOIN query for multiple table's selected Columns using Constructor In The Select Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47726605/3425489) **thank you**

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old post, but you can also use for HQL:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT code AS code FROM Product");
```

or this for SQL:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT code AS code FROM Product");
```

with:

```
query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MyCustomList.class));
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `setResultTransformer` is deprecated as of Hibernate 5.2