# hibernate named query with object

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, named-query

I put this in my District.hbm.xml file

```
<sql-query name="getCarsPerDistrict">
    <return alias="district" class="java.lang.Object"/>
    <![CDATA[SELECT id, name, district_code, count(*) ....]]>
</sql-query>
```

In my DaoImpl i want to access it like this:

```
List<Object[]> objects = (List<Object[]>)session.getNamedQuery("getCarsPerDistrict").list();
```

I need to access it as a List of Objects because otherwise i dont know how to handle the count(*) field in my District Object. Or is it somehow possible to map the count(*) to a variable in java?
I get this error msg: `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Object`

My district class looks like this:

```
private int id;
private String name;
private int district_code;
@Transient
private long carsQuantity;
```

Comment: I dont know which advantage this would bring me?

Comment: You are right (still not fully awaken)... A better idea is creating a new object or list inside the select http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027805/new-object-with-hql