# hibernate HQL createQuery() list() type cast to model directly

Tags: hibernate, model-view-controller, struts2

When I use list() of Hibernate (HQL) after createQuery(), then I want to directly type cast `List<Object[]>` to my `List<POJO class>`. I describe my actual scenario here. I have 3 Plain Old Java Objects say Person, Operation and Project and a table say Transaction with foreign references to  Person , Operation and Project.

```
class Person {
  String name;
  // getters and setters
}

class Operation {
  String name;
  // getters and setters
}

class Project {
  String name;
  // getters and setters
}

class Transaction {
  String p_id;
  String o_id;
  String project_id;
  // refers to id of All three table above
}
```

Now, I want to execute a Hibernate Query Language query say 
 `String query="select p.name, o.name, project.name from Person p , Operation  o, Project project , Transaction t where p.id=2 and p.id=t.p_id and o.id=t.o_id and project.id=t.project_id"`.

I  have created a Model class for output of this query say POP_Model.

```
private class POP_Model {
  String person_name;
  String operation_name;
  String project_name;
}
```

Now, I want to use Hibernate query:

```
Session session=HibernateConnection.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Query q=session.createQuery(query);
List<POP_Model> list=(List<POP_Model>)q.list();
```

It gives typecast error saying Object[] cannot be converted to POP_Model. I checked out TypedQuery but didn't get an example for it. But as far as  I know, TypedQuery can be used to map to POJO not Model. I want to directly type cast to Model.

Comment: One of the approaches for better resolve the problem is to switch to the criteria API.

Comment: "Criteria Api" means? can you refer any link for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are OK with using the JPA API (which Hibernate implements as well) instead of the Hibernate API for this, you can use  JPQL  constructor queries:

```
List<DTO> dtos = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT NEW com.example.DTO( p.name, o.name) FROM Entity o").getResultList();
```

**EDIT** It looks like Hibernate implements constructor expressions with it's regular API as well:

```
List<DTO> dtos = session.createQuery("SELECT NEW com.example.DTO( p.name, o.name) FROM Entity o").list();
```

**EDIT2** JPA is a Java EE standard, unifying working with different persistence libraries like Hibernate and EclipseLink. The [**oracle tutorial**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html) is quite decent.

You can retrieve an EntityManager in a non-EE application like this:

```
  @PersistenceUnit
  private EntityManagerFactory emf;
  ...
  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Comment: I have come across JPA API for the first time. Can you suggest me good links of JPA Example. I am using Struts 2 Application. Secondly, how can I get entityManager object?

Comment: @Misha - have added some detials, hope it can help you further. IMO you should not get bogged down learning a new API, hibernate offers this feature natively, so I would go with the hibernate version for now, keeeping JPA in mind for later.

Comment: @kostja- What would will happen when my query returns list of Model objects? like if I want query like this  `String query="select p.name, o.name, project.name from Person p , Operation o, Project project , Transaction t where    p.id>2    and p.id=t.p_id and o.id=t.o_id and project.id=t.project_id`

Comment: @Misha - I'm afraid I dont quite understand the question. The essence of constructor expressions is that you can assemble all the single attributes of different entities in a different type using the NEW operator. If you wrap it like this: `select NEW com.example.Model(p.name, o.name, project.name)` you can leave the rest of the query as is and get a list of Model objects as result. If this does not answer your question, feel free to explain a bit more in-depth what you mean and I will try to answer.

Answer (score 3):

First create a constructor on the POJO class.

```
private class POP_Model {
  String person_name;
  String operation_name;
  String project_name;

  public POP_Model(String person_name, String operation_name, String project_name){
      this.person_name = person_name;
      this.operation_name = operation_name;
      this.project_name = project_name;
  }
}
```

Then you can use

```
select new com.server.dtos.POP_Model(p.name, o.name, project.name) 
from Transaction t INNER JOIN t.operation o
INNER JOIN t.person p 
INNER JOIN t.project project  
where p.id=2
```

For Reference, here is the [official documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select).
Go through [New object with HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028340/432903) as well.