# Hibernate equivalent of getTimestamp() and getInt()

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I am currently using ResultSet but want to switch over to Hibernate queries.

I have this code:

```
Statement stmt = nfCon.createStatement();
stmt = nfCon.createStatement();
ResultSet foo = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

String str = " " + foo.getTimestamp("time").getTime()  + ", " + foo.getInt("len");
```

How can I change it if I am using

```
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List<String> list = query.list();
```

Obviously, I can't do `list.getTimestamp("time");`. My SQL/HQL is a select statement. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select xxx as time, yyy as len from zzz where ...

List<Object[]> list = query.list(); 

for (Object[] row : list) {
   Date date = (Date) row[0];
   int len = ((Number) row[1]).intValue();
   String str = " " + date.getTime()  + ", " + len;
}
```

This is a general solution. If `len` is a mapped integer field of an entity, then you can cast it directly to `int` (or better `Integer`, especially if it is nullable).

You might also want to look at [constructor invocation from HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027805/new-object-with-hql), as it could help reduce the boilerplate code involved when representing projected columns as `Object` arrays.