# How to write HQL JOIN query for multiple table's selected Columns using Constructor In The Select Clause

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, hql

I'm writing  HQL JOIN query for **multiple table's selected Columns** using `Constructor()` **In The Select Clause**

I have following **Entities**:

**Entity 1: NotificationObject.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="notification_object")
public class NotificationObject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @Column( columnDefinition="INT(10) UNSIGNED" )
    private Integer id;

    @Column( name="entity_type_id", columnDefinition="TINYINT UNSIGNED", nullable=false )
    private Short entityTypeId;

    @Column( name="entity_id", columnDefinition="INT(10) UNSIGNED", nullable=false )
    private Integer entityId;

    @DateTimeFormat( pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" )
    @Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column( name="created_on"/*, nullable=false*/ )
    private Date createdOn;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "notificationObject" )
    private Set<Notification> notifications = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public NotificationObject() {}
    public NotificationObject(Short entityTypeId, Integer entityId) {
        this.entityTypeId = entityTypeId;
        this.entityId = entityId;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**Entity 2: NotificationChange.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="notification_change")
public class NotificationChange implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition="INT(10) UNSIGNED")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne( fetch=FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn(
            name="notification_object_id", nullable=false,
            foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="fk_notification_change_notification_object_noti_object_id")
    )
    private NotificationObject notificationObject;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn( 
            name="actor_id", columnDefinition="INT(10) UNSIGNED", nullable=false,
            foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="fk_notification_change_user_user_id")
    )
    private User actor;

    public NotificationChange() {}
    public NotificationChange( User actor ) {
        this.actor = actor;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**Entity 3: Notification.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="notification")
public class Notification implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @Column( columnDefinition="INT(10) UNSIGNED" )
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne( fetch=FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn(
            name="notification_object_id", nullable=false,
            foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="fk_notification_notification_object_notification_object_id")
    )
    private NotificationObject notificationObject;

    @ManyToOne( fetch=FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn(
            name="notifier_id", columnDefinition="INT(10) UNSIGNED", nullable=false,
            foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="fk_notification_user_user_id")
    )
    private User notifier;

    @Column( name="is_seen", nullable=false )
    private boolean isSeen;

    @Column( name="is_viewed", nullable=false )
    private boolean isViewed;

    public Notification() {}
    public Notification( User notifier, boolean isSeen, boolean isViewed ) {
        this.notifier = notifier;
        this.isSeen = isSeen;
        this.isViewed = isViewed;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**Entity 4: User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private String user_id;

    // Extra fields

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="emp_id", columnDefinition="INT(10) UNSIGNED")
    private Employee employee;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy="notifier" )
    private Set<Notification> notifications = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public User() {}
    public User(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**Entity 5: Employee.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Employee() { }
    public Employee( String emp_id ) {
        this.emp_id = emp_id;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="emp_id")
    private String emp_id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String first_name;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String last_name;

    // Extra fields

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="employee")
    @JsonBackReference
    private User user;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**DTO 1: Notify.java**

```
public class Notify {
    private Integer notificationObjectId, notificationId, notifierId, actorId, entityId;
    private Short entityTypeId;
    private String notifierName, actorName, message, notificationLink;
    private Date createdOn;
    private boolean isSeen, isViewed;

    public Notify() {}
    public Notify ( Integer notificationObjectId, Integer notificationId, Integer notifierId, Integer actorId,
            Integer entityId, Short entityTypeId, String notifierName, String actorName, String message,
            String notificationLink, Date createdOn, boolean isSeen, boolean isViewed ) {
        // Set Values Here
    }
    public Notify (Integer notificationObjectId, Integer notificationId, Integer notifierId, String notifierName, 
            Integer actorId, String actorName, Integer entityId, Short entityTypeId, 
            Date createdOn, boolean isSeen, boolean isViewed ) {
        // Or Here
    }

    // Getters and Setters          
}
```

**I'm weak at JOINs.**
I want to write HQL JOIN query for entity's selected field to form `Constructor()` **In The Select Clause** of `Notify.java` **DTO**.
What I have tried:

**Query 1**

```
final String GET_NOTIFICATIONS_FOR_USER =
"select new support.dto.Notify ( no.id, n.id, Integer.parseInt( n.notifier.user_id ), "
+ "concat ( n.notifier.employee.first_name, ' ', n.notifier.employee.last_name ), "
+ "Integer.parseInt( nc.actor.user_id ), concat( nc.actor.employee.first_name, ' ', nc.actor.employee.last_name ), "
+ "no.entityId, no.entityTypeId, no.createdOn, n.isSeen, n.isViewed ) "
+ "from Notification n, NotificationObject no, NotificationChange nc, User u, Employee e "
+ "where n.notifier.user_id = :notifierId";
```

**Query 2**

```
final String GET_NOTIFICATIONS_FOR_USER =
"select new support.dto.Notify ( no.id, n.id, Integer.parseInt( n.notifier.user_id ), "
+ "concat ( n.notifier.employee.first_name, ' ', n.notifier.employee.first_name ), "
+ "Integer.parseInt( nc.actor.user_id ), concat( nc.actor.employee.first_name, ' ', nc.actor.employee.last_name ), "
+ "no.entityId, no.entityTypeId, no.createdOn, n.isSeen, n.isViewed ) "
+ "from NotificationChange nc inner join nc.notificationObject no "
+ "inner join no.notifications n "
+ "where n.notifier.user_id = :notifierId";
```

**I'm getting following Exception**

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.getConstructor(ReflectHelper.java:309)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructor(ConstructorNode.java:174)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.prepare(ConstructorNode.java:144)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processConstructor(HqlSqlWalker.java:1091)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2328)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2194)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1476)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:573)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:298)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1821)
>       at support.DAO.MasterDaoImpl.getNotifications(MasterDaoImpl.java:115)
>       at support.service.MasterServiceImpl.getNotifications(MasterServiceImpl.java:158)
>       at support.service.MasterServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a355463b.invoke()
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
>       at support.service.MasterServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8c2728e2.getNotifications()
>       at support.controller.WebSocketController.hello(WebSocketController.java:91)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:447)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:443)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:82)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:408)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:346)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:135)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that Hibernate couldn't locate the `Notify`  constructor.

More, you are not allowed to add `Integer.parseInt` in your HQL query. Use the expected type from the ResultSet and do the casting inside the constructor from the incoming parameter.

Comment: Is my query correct? What is correct way of jointing tables **(HQL JOINS)**?

Comment: I have remove `Integer.parseInt()`, and Done casting in `Notify Constructor()`, now got by exception `org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to commit against JDBC connection` root caused `com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (3223602 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.`

Comment: **Query 1** gives above exception,  **Query 2** works fine, could you please tell me **Optimized Query** for above situation?, Or could you please  tell me How to use **JOINS** in **HQL Queries**, any **blog** from you ?  **thank you**

Comment: Could you please give me  **Optimized query** for example purpose for above situation? **thank you**