# Hibernate criteria for many to one, ignore a column when retrieving data?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have 3 Entities.

1. Employee.
2. Ticket.
3. Comment.

Each of them has one-to-many relationships with each other. I need to retrieve a record of single **Ticket**. But when I am getting the data along with it comes the data of the employee mapped to it. In the employee data that is coming, **I don't want the password field data to be retrieved along with the other fields. SO WHAT MUST BE THE CRITERIA QUERY FOR THIS**

**EMPLOYEE CLASS**

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "getUserByEmail", query = "from Employee where emaillAddress = :emailAddress")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "employee_id", updatable = false)
    private int empId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name ="emp_code" ,unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long employeeCode;

    @Column(name = "full_name", nullable = false)
    private String fullName;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "email_address", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String emaillAddress;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;


    @Column(name = "employee_role", nullable = false)
    private int role;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<>();

    public Employee() {
        this.fullName = "";
        this.password = "";
        this.emaillAddress = "";
        this.role = 2;
    }
}
```

**TICKET CLASS**

```
@Entity
public class Ticket {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int ticketId;
    private String title;
    private String message;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TicketPriority priority;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TicketStatus status;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TicketType type;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy | HH:mm",timezone="Asia/Kolkata")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date timestamp;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    Employee owner;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ticket", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    public Ticket() {
        super();
        this.title = "";
        this.message = "";
        timestamp = new Date();
        this.status = TicketStatus.RAISED;
    }
}
```

**COMMENT CLASS**

```
@Entity
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int commentId;
    private String message;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="comment_owner")
    Employee employee;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ticket_id")
    Ticket ticket;

}
```

> Query i am using is **return getCurrentSession().get(Ticket.class, id);**
>
> This is the toString of the Ticket object i am getting
>
> Ticket [ticketId=5, title=WFH, message=i need to work from home tomorrow, priority=IMMEDIATE, status=RAISED, type=WFH_REQUEST, owner=Employee [empId=1, employeeCode=123, fullName=emp, emaillAddress=emp, password=emp, role=2, tickets=], comments=[]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two different `Employee` entities for the same table Employee.

In one of them you map the column `password` and in the other entity you not map the `password`.

So when your intention is retrieve the entity without the password, use this new entity `EmployeeWithoutPassword`. For the rest of the cases (insert, update, etc), just use the regular entity with all fields.

You can also [use customized DTOs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028340/2387977) to accomplish this without create a new entity, just returning the fields you want.

Comment: Thanx, i am now making DTO's for UI

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Transient` as

```
@Transient
private String password;
```

This annotation specifies that the property or field is not persistent. It is used to annotate a property or field of an entity class, mapped superclass, or embeddable class.

Comment: @Transient will not save the value of password in the database. I just dont want the password when i am reading the ticket by id, along with it the emp also come, in that emp i dont want the password feild as you can see the toString of object i pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this annotation:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "password")
```

It works fine for me.